# Android conflict version gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle

im having a problem on my build.gradle which is a version conflict with firebase-auth and the com.google.android.gms.

**Error [message printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RToV.png)**

**Gradle source**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "pt.tomasdealmeida.sotreta"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.6.2'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

change this

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.6.2'
```

to

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
```

and please cek this [Release Note](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases)

December 18, 2017 - Google Play services 11.8.0 release